# Storing conditional logic for compliance in a database

Tags: database, oracle, database-design, data-structures, ads

I'm creating advertise system, which should be shown on ATM. For now, I have to make a database structure where advertise, ATM and customer compliance will be stored.

> Advertise system must choose an advertise depending on ATM and
>   customer.

The point is that customer is not strictly defined. It can be filtered with any its property (card number, account, client ID, client age, ...). 
For example:

1. On ATM=1 ADV=2 should be shown when customer is card like '1111%' On
2. All ATM except ATM=1 ADV=3 should be shown when ClientID in (1,2)

**How Can I store these data in relational database?**

I have one solution, but I don't like it, I will make a table were SQL where causes will be saved. 
For example:

> **advertise table** 
> Adv_ID 
> Terminal_ID 
> Status (values can be: Allow/deny) 
> rule (here will be written SQL filter, for
>   example: "card like '1111%' and client_id !=10230")
> screen_id (on
>   which page this adv must be shown)    order (for adv priority)

Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: How many of these columns do you have, will your conditions only be connected by the `AND` operator, is there more than `IN`, `LIKE` (and both combined with `NOT`), and who will maintain this configuration?

Comment: Conditions will be connected with only AND operator. And there will be used IN, LIKE, NOT IN, NOT LIKE, =, !=. This configurations will be maintained with the specialists of ATM software from UI. But for now, I'm writing only web service for configurations.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to design your configuration like this:

- columns

  - column_name
  - data_type (`NUMBER`, `VARCHAR`)
- advertisements

  - adv
  - seq (to assign priority)
- conditions

  - adv (FK)
  - column_name (FK)
  - modifier: `NOT` (check-constraint)
  - operator: `LIKE`, `IN` (would cover `=` and `!=` but you can also add them explicitely)
  - values (child-table)

This would allow to generate all conditions while avoiding typos and SQL injection. I added `data_type` to check when only numbers are allowed and when quotes need to be added/escaped.

```
adv column_name  modifier  operator  values (shown denormalized)
2   atm                    IN        1
2   customer               LIKE      1111%
3   atm          NOT       IN        1
3   clientID               IN        1,2
```